# Font:size not working in ipad for Html table

Tags: css, ipad, html, media-queries

i have coding simple html layout and for a  html table   i have set font-size:9px;  now when i check it in  ipad my font is    bigger than that , for example i have set it like this

```
<td width="52" height="56" valign="top" style="font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, Helv
etica, sans-serif;">
<div align="left" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;">

Text goes here 

</div>
</td>
```

i have gine inline style to div , even inline style for td as well but it does not work , i did try

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    body{font-size:9px !important;}
 }
```

but still its looking more than 12px how can i set it to 11px for ipad please help me with it .

Comment: Does it *look* larger, or *is it* larger?  Did you Firebug it? (Yes, you can use Firebug on an iPad).

Comment: it looks larger , maybe inheriting some other code i m checking using litmus.com cant firebug

Comment: Why can't you Firebug?  Google `Firebug iPad`, and you'll find several articles that will instruct you how to install / use Firebug on your iPad.

Comment: i  m  using litmus.com to test it that give me screenshot of  how it looks , i dont have ipad :)

Answer (score 1):

iPads and iPhones make the min text 15 px or soemthing like that. add "-webkit-text-size-adjust: none" in the style

Answer (score 0):

Use em values.

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;  //16px
}
body {
  font-size:68.75%;  //11px
}

table {
  font-size:0.8181em;  //9px
}
```

Now all will be based on 11px = 1em;  If you want 14px then it will be 14/11 = 1.2727em

```
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
     table {font-size:0.8181em;}
 }
```